# revert all the pushed commits to a few files

Tags: git

I have made changes to a few files that I want to revert. I want to revert all the commits made on a branch from a few files. I have tried using git checkout but there are a lot of commits to those files and it makes the process very long. Is there any other way?

Comment: You need to clarify what's going on here. How many commits are involved? What specific changes are you trying to "undo"?

Comment: There are a lot of commits (2-3) to the files I want to revert. I want to undo all the changes from a few files say for example, in a branch, all commits to the file a.txt should get reverted. Let me know if there are more details that I am missing

Comment: "all commits to the file a.txt should get reverted" - see, that just doesn't make sense, every time `a.txt` gets changed, you record that change in a commit, so are you saying that you just want to drop `a.txt` from the repo?

Comment: In any case, it sounds like you want `git checkout $(git merge-base master <your-branch>) -- a.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git checkout for just a single file or directory:

`git checkout <hash> -- /path/to/file`

First you should find the hash when your files were ok with git log.